# Xcode 4 Templates—How to add license to beginning of file?

Tags: xcode, macos, templates, xcode4, plist

[image]
 I've spent hours trying to figure this out. In my custom Xcode 4 template, I have a checkbox option to include the zlib/libpng license at the top of each source file. Trouble is, no matter what I do I can't make it tack it on to the beginning of the file AND keep the rest of the file. It either shows `// THIS IS A TEST` and nothing else, or the whole file but not the test comment.

I've tried what is shown in the screenshot above and dozens of other things. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I figured it out, finally. As you can see in the image above, for every source file I have two rules, :comments and :content. In the Definitions, I set the :content of each to the rest of the file (all in a big string), and in the option i set just the comments of every file depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not. Since the definitions for the files are now strings, not paths, I had to keep the dictionaries for the header files just to keep the `<key>TargetIndices</key> <array/>` so they don't get added to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.